# Python interpretation of bytes. (C memcpy)

Tags: c, python-3.x, memcpy

i am new in python. I try to rewrite some c++ code in python, i get data from serial port (we used our own protocol) and need to convert bytes to value in C++ i use something like this (bytes in little endian but we can get custom start bits and bitLength)

```
long getLong(size_t startBit, size_t countBit, unsigned char* data)
{
    long lResult = 0L;
    long L1;
    for (i = 0; i < countBit; i++)
    {
        L1 = long(data[(i+startBit)/8] >> ((i+startBit)%8)) & 1L;
        lResult = (lResult & ~(1L << i)) | (L1 << i);
    }
    return lResult;
}
```

value can`t be more than 4 byte thats why i use long
and sometimes value can be float, than i just use long from this function and do memcpy to reinterpret bytes

```
{
        float res;
        memcpy(&res,&longValue,sizeof(float)); 
        result=res;
        break;
}
```

in python i get the list of unsigned char from C++ lib (obviosly int in python)
and i can get long value the same c++ way with bitwise operations

```
def _bytes_to_val(self, byte_list, start_bit, count_bit):
    result=0
    for i in range(0,count_bit):
        val = (byte_list[(i+start_bit)//8] >> ((i+start_bit)%8)) & 1
        result = (result & ~(1 << i)) | (val << i)
    return result
```

but how to get float? I read about byteArray but it is string representation and python use only double standart for floating point values. Only think came to me is append this function to c++ lib but i suppose must be other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much work.

```
>>> struct.unpack('i', b'\xdb\x0fI@')
(1078530011,)
>>> struct.unpack('f', b'\xdb\x0fI@')
(3.1415927410125732,)
```

Comment: But what about bitwise operation to specify start bits and lentgh in bits (not bytes) Do i understand right that i need use first functions with bitwise operation and convert result to bytes later or struct.unpack can deal with custom bits too? i didnt see it in official tutorial?

Comment: [bitarray](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/) can handle the bit operations.